# How to pad arrays by a variable amount?

Tags: python, arrays, padding

I am trying to make multiple PNG files the same size. I do not want to alter the image, simply add borders around all of them until they are all the same size as the largest PNG file.
The language is Python.

It is a large amount of files so I am unable to do this manually. I am using a for loop. I already know what the maximum size is: (100, 441). maxImage represents this. images is the name of my arrays.

```
for n in range(0, len(images - 1)):
    stat_length = maxImage - len(images[n])
    hello = py.pad(images[n], 1, 'constant')
    print (hello[n].shape)
```

This is my code. I would like to know how to pad by a variable amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
import numpy as np
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
p = np.shape(a)
max_h = 100 
max_w = 441
pad_h = (max_h-p[0])//2
pad_w = (max_w-p[1])//2 
print(np.pad(a,((pad_h,pad_h),(pad_w,pad_w)),'constant', constant_values=(0)))
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. It provides something I had not thought of using before, which is tuples. Unfortunately I am getting the error message: TypeError: `pad_width` must be of integral type.

Edit: i changed pad_h to (max_h - p[0])//2 (and pad_w) and it works perfectly now! Thank you for your help.

Comment: great: modified the response to guarantee an `int`. Can you approve the answer?